# How to make certain objects hidden when CSS Sticky footer bar floats over

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sticky-footer

I have a mildly transparent sticky footer that I've taken from CSS bootstrap and I was wondering how to make specific properties within various css selectors have values that make them opacity=0 or similar, (i.e., so that they are hidden) when the transparent sticky footer floats over.

Is there a tried and tested method for this...? Perhaps a javascript method...? I was perhaps thinking we could select the sticky-bar class:

```
.sticky-bar {}
```

And then implement what classes it can hide when over, hypothetically "something" like:

```
.sticky-bar: over {
  hide: .class_1, .class_2;
}
```

I'm just not sure on the variables or if such variables even exist!

If someone could point me in the right direction or give me a started for 10 that would be much appreciated.

```css
.border {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 3000px;
}

.sticky-bar {
  background: #000000;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #D3D3D3;
  font-weight: 300;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0.9;
  padding: 0em;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99999;
}
.sticky-bar-inner {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  padding: 3px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #000000;
}
.sticky-bar-inner p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 11px;
}
#footerlist {
  padding-left: 0;
}
#footerlist li {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Border -->
<div class="border"></div>

<!-- Footer -->
<div class="sticky-bar">
  <div class="sticky-bar-inner">
    <p>&#169;2015 The astrobox.io Project
      <p>
        <ul id="footerlist">
          <li class="social">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/astroboxio">
              <img src="https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/astroboxio_twitter_circle_black-512.png?_subject_uid=209608449&w=AABCg-2Bh2udLb-vzQz3ryyFfhfEAOtcU2apWFBOG6GHlw" height="42" width="42"></img>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="social">
            <a href="https://github.com/astroboxio">
              <img src="https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/astroboxio_github_circle_black-512.png?_subject_uid=209608449&w=AADU4Aqt57dkrlupJ1TDzuYpCkOf3OjCChT9l-M6m79fTQ" height="42" width="42"></img>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="social">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/astroboxio_vimeo_circle_black-512.png?_subject_uid=209608449&w=AADDZg0zdYQML7E7v6eo4bJ4eku4VoV4HJgO9CgemmWIuA" height="42" width="42"></img>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my jsfiddle of my stick footer thus far:

[Sticky Footer: jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michealjroberts/89papu02/)

Comment: Can you post an example of sticky footer you use, possibly a jsfiddle; Sticky footer would actually not allow elements pass through it ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, are you only trying to make the footer on top of every other markup? If so you only need to set z-index.

Comment: @PierreArlaud Well from the css the opacity is set to 0.9 which is nice because images fade out underneath but I have some horizontal lines across certain divs and these don't look very nice at all. I was wondering if I could chose specific divs to be hidden when the sticky bar floats over...take a look at my added border divot see what I mean.

Comment: @NenadP Take a look at: jsfiddle.net/michealjroberts/89papu02

Comment: @MichaelRoberts I don't see any horizontal lines or any similar problems in your fiddle. Can you add some so we can see the *actual* problem?

Comment: @PierreArlaud If you could edit the js fiddle with the new border div and border class css that I've added to the question. I'm AFK at the minute for about 6 hours. :/

Comment: You need to play with z-index indeed. But if your image is child of the div, I don't see any ways to show the image but not its parent...

Comment: @MichaelRoberts Did you manage to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add an opaque layer under the sticky bar. That way, objects with a depth between the two will be transparent, and those under will be invisible. Please note that elements need to be `position: relative` to be over the opaque layout.

Check this snippet:

```css
.border {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 3000px;
}
img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 150;
}
.sticky-background {
    z-index: 100;
    height: 99px;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}
.sticky-bar {
  z-index: 200;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #D3D3D3;
  font-weight: 300;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 1.0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.sticky-bar-inner {
  opacity: 0.9;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  padding: 3px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #000000;
}
.sticky-bar-inner p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 11px;
}
#footerlist {
  padding-left: 0;
}
#footerlist li {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.ndaccess.com/sample/Images/Image1.jpg" style="margin-top: 100px;"/>
<div class="border"></div>

<!-- Footer -->
<div class="sticky-background"></div>
<div class="sticky-bar">
  <div class="sticky-bar-inner">
    <p>&#169;2015 The astrobox.io Project
      <p>
        <ul id="footerlist">
          <li class="social">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/astroboxio">
              <img src="https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/astroboxio_twitter_circle_black-512.png?_subject_uid=209608449&w=AABCg-2Bh2udLb-vzQz3ryyFfhfEAOtcU2apWFBOG6GHlw" height="42" width="42"></img>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="social">
            <a href="https://github.com/astroboxio">
              <img src="https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/astroboxio_github_circle_black-512.png?_subject_uid=209608449&w=AADU4Aqt57dkrlupJ1TDzuYpCkOf3OjCChT9l-M6m79fTQ" height="42" width="42"></img>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="social">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/astroboxio_vimeo_circle_black-512.png?_subject_uid=209608449&w=AADDZg0zdYQML7E7v6eo4bJ4eku4VoV4HJgO9CgemmWIuA" height="42" width="42"></img>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```